# Why does Files.isWritable() method return true for a directory even when it is set to read only?

Tags: java

I have explicitly set read only mode both through `setReadOnly` method as well as `setWritable(false)`.

```
File file  = new File(myDir);
file.setReadOnly();
file.setWritable(false);
file.setExecutable(false);
return file.canWrite();
```

I also checked through windows explorer that the specified directory is marked read-only:

[image]

In the above example , the `file.canWrite` returns true. Is there a stricter way of enforcing read only mode?

Comment: But can you really write to it? By which is meant, create or delete a file in it? That's a different issue from `canWrite()` reporting a wrong value.

Comment: "Read-only (**Only applies to files in folder**)"?

Comment: @user207421 The issue is I am using a third party library (sleepycat Berkeley db), which checks for file.canWrite and throws Exception if true. Since I cannot change it's code, only option I have is to set the read only flag correctly through my code.

Comment: Well you're doing that. Is this a network folder?

Comment: Does the third party library expect a directory path or nothing specific?

Comment: @user207421 No. Folder on local disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api specification for [java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) states the following as kind of disclaimer -

> A file system may implement restrictions to certain operations on the
>   actual file-system object, such as reading, writing, and executing.
>   These restrictions are collectively known as access permissions. The
>   file system may have multiple sets of access permissions on a single
>   object. For example, one set may apply to the object's owner, and
>   another may apply to all other users. The access permissions on an
>   object may cause some methods in this class to fail.

And definitely this is the case with you. On Linux(Ubuntu-18.04) things look to be very normal and as per specification.
Outputs for the following code using Java sdk-1.8.0_222 in the 2 environments is printed below

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      File f = null;
      boolean bool = false;

      try {

         // create new file
         f = new File("test");

         f.setWritable(false);
         bool = f.canWrite();
         System.out.println("Can write to test: "+bool);
         f.setWritable(true);
         bool = f.canWrite();
         System.out.println("Can write to test: "+bool+"\n\n");

                 f.mkdir();
                 //f.createNewFile();

                 f.setWritable(false);
         bool = f.canWrite();
         System.out.println("Can write to test: "+bool);
         f.setWritable(false);
         bool = f.canWrite();
         System.out.println("Can write to test: "+bool);

      } catch(Exception e) {

         // if any I/O error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Windows (file) -

```
C:\Users\rranjan\Desktop>java FileDemo
Can write to test: false
Can write to test: false


Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true

C:\Users\rranjan\Desktop>java FileDemo
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true


Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true
```

Linux (file) -

```
rranjan@my-workstation:~/scratch/java$ java FileDemo
Can write to test: false
Can write to test: false


Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true
rranjan@my-workstation:~/scratch/java$ java FileDemo
Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true


Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true
```

Windows (directory) -

```
C:\Users\rranjan\Desktop>java FileDemo
Can write to test: false
Can write to test: false


Can write to test: true
Can write to test: true

C:\Users\rranjan\Desktop>java FileDemo
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Can write to test: true
Can write to test: true


Can write to test: true
Can write to test: true
```

Linux (directory) -

```
rranjan@my-workstation:~/scratch/java$ java FileDemo
Can write to test: false
Can write to test: false


Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true
rranjan@my-workstation:~/scratch/java$ java FileDemo
Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true


Can write to test: false
Can write to test: true
```

Now, you can observe that for a file or directory, if it doesn't exist, `canWrite()` is always `False`.
After the file/directory is created on a Linux platform, for both a file as well as a directory, setting writeable works seamlessly. Whereas, on a Windows box, directory seems to return true whatsoever. This is the kind of behavior which I quoted in the above lines.

Comment: thanks for the detailed info. Do you know of a stricter way to enforce these restrictions?